# How did Blank Banshee extract such a clean sample from Grandmaster Flash's The Message?

Tags: production, samples, isolation

This song from Blank Banshee--

takes a clean sample from this classic song--

The original song being as old as it is and recorded the way it was, there can't possibly be stems for it, can there? And besides that, Blank Banshee was just some bedroom producer back then so even if there were stems I have no idea how he would have gotten a hold of them. Is it seriously even possible to chop that clean of a sample from the original? I have no idea how he isolated it so well if that's the case. I can't find any breaks in the rest of the instrumentals throughout the original song... any ideas?

Comment: I can't determine what you are asking. That sample looks relatively straightforward to use, especially the way it is used in the Banshee number.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a synth patch he created with some delay and reverb. Getting there roughly is pretty easy if you know your synths. Sine base with some FM modulation and lfo filters.